# JSON org.json.JSONException: No value for "NAME"

Tags: android, arrays, json

I am getting an error while trying to get information from a JSON file. I am trying to get the data from the 'post', such as 'NAME', 'YEAR' etc and print it to the log. It keeps telling me `org.json.JSONException: No value for NAME`. Can someone point me in the right direction?

JSON Example:

```
{"posts":[
{"post":{"ID":"74",
    "TOURN_ID":"999",
    "YEAR":"2016",
    "START_DATE":"2016-09-07",
    "END_DATE":"2016-09-18",
    "DATE_STRING":"September 7th - 18th 2016",
    "NAME":"2016 Paralympic Games",
    "ShortName":"2016 Paralympic Games",
    "TOURN_TYPE":"International"}},

{"post":{"ID":"73",
    "TOURN_ID":"999",
    "YEAR":"2016",
    "START_DATE":"2016-06-23",
    "END_DATE":"2016-06-25",
    "DATE_STRING":"June 22nd - 23rd 2016",
    "NAME":"2016 USABA National Goalball Championships",
    "ShortName":"2016 US Nationals",
    "TOURN_TYPE":"Domestic"}},

{"post":{"ID":"72",
    "TOURN_ID":"999",
    "YEAR":"2016",
    "START_DATE":"2016-05-12",
    "END_DATE":"2016-05-14",
    "DATE_STRING":"May 12th-14th 2016",
    "NAME":"2016 USABA Western Regional Goalball Tournament",
    "ShortName":"2016 Utah",
    "TOURN_TYPE":"Domestic"}}
]}
```

Here is my Java:

```
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
     super.onPostExecute(result);

     try {
         JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);

         String tournInfo = jsonObject.getString("posts");

       Log.i("Tourn Info", tournInfo); // displays correctly

         JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(tournInfo);

         for(int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++){


             JSONObject jsonPart = arr.getJSONObject(i);

             String name = jsonPart.optString("NAME");

             Log.i("Each Tournament Object", jsonPart.getString("post"));// Work correctly displays all the 'post' items
```

This is where I get my error:

```
Log.i("Name of Tournament", jsonPart.getString("NAME"));
```

Comment: JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(jsonObject.getJSONArray("posts")); and remove the toudnInfo line.---  Edit. Sorry, it's actually: JSONObject jsonPart = arr.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("post");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have proven, this works:

```
Log.i("Each Tournament Object", jsonPart.getString("post"));
```

This means that when you get your jsonPart object, the first level is the "post" object (Which is redundant). So you need to operate another level down

```
JSONObject jsonObjectPost = jsonPart.getObject("post");
```

then

```
Log.i("Name of Tournament", jsonObjectPost.getString("NAME"));
```